# How do I efficiently reuse a clipped image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

For a board game I am making, i have to design a map comprised of hexagonal tiles. The geography of the map (forests, mountains etc) is represented by the tile's image, and as such. I need to clip a hexagonal region off several images, and use them again and again. Before I can start designing the map, i need to make sure each individual tile works as expected. However I am stuck. This is the code for the `Tile` class

```
 var Tile = function (startX, startY, l, img) {


this.side = l; //length of the hexagon's size
this.startingPoint = [startX, startY];
this.image = img;

this.incrX = Math.sqrt(3)*this.side/2;
this.incrY = this.side/2;

this.points = [
    this.startingPoint,
    [startX + this.incrX, startY - this.incrY],
    [startX + 2*this.incrX, startY],
    [startX + 2*this.incrX, startY + this.side],
    [startX + this.incrX, startY + this.side + this.incrY],
    [startX, startY + this.side]
]; //list of points comprising the path for making the hexagonal tile

this.middlePoint = [startX + this.incrX, startY + this.side/2];


//draws the hexagonal tile
this.show = function (context) {

    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.startingPoint[0], this.startingPoint[1]); //starting at the starting point (duh)

    for(var i=1; i<this.points.length; i++){
        context.lineTo(this.points[i][0], this.points[i][1]); //looping through the rest of the points
    }

    context.closePath(); //closing the path
    if(this.image){
        context.clip();
        context.drawImage(this.image, 50, 20);
    }
    context.restore();
    context.stroke();
}

}
```

And to test the correctness of the code I've tried drawing 2 tiles on a canvas:

```
var context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
context.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function () {
  var tile = new Tile(200, 100, 50, img);
  var tile2 = new Tile(200, 400, 50, img);
  tile.show(context);
  tile2.show(context);
}
img.src = "tree.png";
```

The 2 tiles are drawn, but only one of them is actually filled with the image. Besides that, i feel like this code is highly inefficient. The `context.save()` method i had to use is an expensive operation and the need to draw hundreds of tiles brings up some performance issues. Am i going about this correctly? What would be a more efficient way of designing the `Tile` class to avoid performance issues?

Comment: Currently an image is clipped using the coordinates of where it will be drawn - so a tile just reveals that section of a full screen image that lies underneath where the tile is placed- no tile is the same. This could expain why only one of your tile appears. My question for you is did you intend tiles to have fixed content that will be repeated over and over again?

Comment: @Traktor53 Yes the content should be fixed. There will probably be 4-5 different types of tiles but tiles of the same type should look and behave exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Canvas Operations**

The second tile is not appearing because clipping is set up on the canvas for where the tile appears, the canvas has the dimensions of the screen, and the image is drawn from the (x,y) position of ( 50, 20) without scaling. If the image doesn't reach to where the tile is placed, there is no tile content showing. And if it does show, content depends on tile position.

Of the two choices for writing image data to the canvas, `putImageData` and `drawImage`, `putImageData`doesn't implement paint operations which take into account image transparency and so can't be used to juxtapose non-rectangular tiles without obscuring part of an adjacent tile.

[`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) can write the content of HTML image and canvas objects, ImageBitMap objects, SVG objects and more, but unfortunately the list doesn't include [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) objects which can be read directly from a written canvas.

ImageData objects can be converted to ImageBitMap objects, but the factory function is asynchronous and uses promises, so you would want to prepare the tiles and convert their content to bit maps before first use.

This leaves multiple ways of achieving fast tile writing.

1. Load an Image object. For each tile from the image,

   - create a canvas element (it doesn't have to be in the DOM) of the tile's rectangular size,
   - create the clip region for the tile in the canvas,
   - write a section of the image to the canvas, using the last parameters of [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) to specify which part of the image to use,
   - store the canvas as a property of a tile object.
   - use `drawImage` to write the tile's canvas property value anywhere you calculate it needs to go.
2. As for 1, but after writing a tile to the canvas, read the image data back and use [createImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) to create a promise for a bit map. When all promises for all tiles for all images have been fulfilled, the tiles can be used.
3. Create an image strip of tiles offline as a row or column of squares of the same size and make areas of each tile that are not to be rendered as transparent. Then as for one or two but omitting setting up the clip region.

I tested the first method to obtain ensure it worked without the need to add canvas elements for each tile to the document. See the snippet. FYI the size of a tile's square was specified and inner `side`, `incX` and `incY` values calculated from it.

Method 2 would probably use less memory, but how much less is uncertain. Method 3 was an idea only. Creating an image strip of similar size icons could be useful anyway and facilitate automatically creating an array of tiles from an image.

Hope it helps.

---

```js
function BlankTile( size) {
    this.size = size;
    this.xInc = size/2;
    this.yInc = this.xInc * Math.tan(Math.PI/6);
    this.side = size - 2* this.yInc;
    this.vTab = this.side+this.yInc;
    
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.canvas.height = this.size;
    this.canvas.width = this.size;
    
    var ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( 0, this.yInc);
    ctx.lineTo( this.xInc, 0);
    ctx.lineTo( this.size, this.yInc);
    ctx.lineTo( this.size, this.yInc + this.side);
    ctx.lineTo( this.xInc, this.side + 2* this.yInc);
    ctx.lineTo( 0, this.yInc + this.side);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

function Tile ( size, image, x, y, width, height) {
    var blank = new BlankTile( size);
    blank.ctx.drawImage( image, x||0, y || 0, width || size, height || size, 0, 0, size, size);
    this.canvas = blank.canvas;
    this.vTab = blank.vTab;
    this.size = size;
}
Tile.prototype.draw = function( context, x, y) {
    context.drawImage( this.canvas, x, y);
}

//  demonstrate code above:

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
   var tile = new Tile( 50, image);
   for( var y = 0, row = 0; y < 400; y += tile.vTab, ++row) {
       for( var x = 0; x < 600; x += tile.size ) {
           var start = row&1 ? tile.size /2 : 0;
           tile.draw( context, start + x, y);
       }
   } 
}
image.src = "data:image/png;base64,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"
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: thin solid blue;" height=400 width=600>
```

Comment: Those ideas should fit my needs just right, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

What about using a single bitmap with all of the images on it and then use CSS **background-position** to perform the clipping?

```
background-position: 13px 0;
```

The demo below shows the source image on the right and the 3 cropped instances on the left

```css
.board {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b7/0a/79/b70a7978cdc41e84c165d46eed433dce.png');
  height: 200px;
}

.image.image1 {
  background-position: -13px 0px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 151px;
}

.image.image2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-position: -30px -302px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 70px;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 60px;
  height: 148px;
}

.image.image3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  background-position: -211px 0px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 150px;
}

.image.full {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 160px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 410px;
  background-size: contain;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="image image1"></div>
  <div class="image image2"></div>
  <div class="image image3"></div>
  <div class="image full"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Once i've done that however, will i be able to access each fragment seperately and interact with it using javascript?

Comment: Yes because each is a dom element so you'd be able to access it and manipulate it in JavaScript.

Comment: Your solution does indeed work! Thank you! However i am planning to upload the game on a platform where i won't be able to use dom elements besides the canvas, so i don't think i can use this. Perhaps setting the visibilty to hidden will so the trick but i'll have to check back with you on that one.

Comment: On second thought I don't think my method is a good approach for your situation. I think you are on the right track with canvas and I like the answer provided. I've been meaning to dive into how the canvas works but haven't had a chance yet.

Comment: I've only just began as well, and from what i've seen so far, the api is rich and there should be no problems once i get the hang of it :)